# How to build your OAuth flow when using Google id token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, openid-connect, spring-security-oauth2, google-identity

My client(front-end) is a native mobile app (built with Flutter). For the backend, I'm using  Spring to expose resources via Rest API endpoints. I want to implement Google Sign-In for my application. Also, I want to use OAuth flow for my own end points.

I found overall flow recommended for this situation [Authenticate with a backend server](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth).
So as I understood **the process is like this**:

I use google sing in my native app and it receives token when user signs in, then the app send it to my authorization server(AS). Then AS just directly sends access (+ refresh) token to the app(i.e client). We can say that it is a password grant type, but instead of using user and password to identify user, AS uses token which we received from google. And when the app calls my Resource server(RS) it uses access token issued by my AS. am I right? PS I draw some diagram showing this flow:

[image: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mvB6InwLAJeVe8DRqPFodyPRAz6lzUhK/view][2].]

In summary, the question is how to build your Oauth flow when you receive google token id? is using **password grant type** recommended for this situation? Does it make sense using **authorization code** flow, considering that my client has already received id token?

Comment: password grant type isnt recommended in any situation

Comment: but I treat google id token as credentials( I create users and identify them in my DB based on id token ). And Google sends them to my client. As far as I know, authorization code flow is meant for not sharing your credentials with the client, but in this case, they are already in my client app since goole sends it to my mobile application. So what should   I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred option if your Authorization Server (AS) supports it, is to do this, which should require zero code changes to your app:

- Your app only connects to your own AS and only uses tokens from your AS - it is standard for your app to use Authorization Code Flow (PKCE)
- The AS redirects to Google and also handles the response, swapping  Google tokens for AS tokens, which are then returned to the app

This won't work if you use the Password Grant however, since this flow does not support federation. If it helps, my [visual blog post](https://authguidance.com/2020/05/23/federation-logins/) has more info on this design pattern.

**GOALS AND TRADE OFFS**

- The **User Experience** should be the same whether or not you use federation
- **Future Extensibility** is worth thinking about - the pattern I describe generally gives you the best options if you want to integrate 3 other login options in future
- **Technical Simplicity** for your UIs and APIs is also worth thinking about - how much code complexity are you adding?

Unfortunately, the technology is often imperfect. I hope at least my comments help you to understand the goals behind the OIDC standards.

**YOUR CODE AND THE LIBRARIES YOU USE**

I would be a bit careful in this area. The [link you referred to](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access) is very Google specific and focused on calling Google APIs to get Google data. If this is your goal then that is fine, but it may limit you if you also want to do non Google stuff.

The code samples on my blog are focused on being OIDC standards based, which starts with using [standard messages](https://authguidance.com/2020/02/22/how-to-run-the-ios-code-sample/). This gives me the best future options, via AppAuth libraries. It is not easy though - the tech is definitely much harder than it should be.

Comment: 1) will the fact that my mobile application doesn't have any other options for sign-in apart from googling affect anything? 2)  how the process will look like for the user now? will he do the same things: click on google sign, enter google credentials and you are done. So the user won't feel any difference compared to the approach when you place your google sign in code inside of your client

Comment: Also could you provide some code solutions for this? I understood your approach but the implementation with all of this redirections confuses me.
PS I found this solution:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access
where google sends authorization code to the client( instead of sending id token) this code is sent to the server, server exchanges this code for an access token and id token. So I feel like this approach issafer than just receiving id token. So what do you think of this? I know your approach should be better, but the implementation kinda baffles me.

Comment: OK - I've added a few bits to my answer above - no quick answer I'm afraid - but making best use of standards is usually the best option